# Sharpoint Online Powershell Search

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Iam trying to search for multiple file types ( movie files) in my sharepoint library and then output to .csv, the script works fine when searching for just one file type but i am struggling when searching for multiple file types

#Variables#

```
$CSVFile = "C:\TEMP\MP4Files.csv"
#$FileType = "mp4"  ( **original text**)
$FileType = @("mp4","exe")   ( **my attempt** )


$DocLibraries = Get-PnPList | Where-Object {$_.BaseTemplate -eq 101}

    $results = @()

foreach ($DocLibrary in $DocLibraries) {
$AllItems = Get-PnPListItem -PageSize 1000 -List $DocLibrary

foreach ($Item in $AllItems) {
if ($Item["FileLeafRef"] -like "*.$FileType") {

$results += [pscustomobject][ordered] @{

ID                = $Item["ID"]
FileName = $Item["FileLeafRef"]
FilePath   = $Item["FileRef"]
SizeInMB = [Math]::Round(($Item["File_x0020_Size"]/1MB),2)

}

      }#end of IF statement
  }
}
$Results | Export-Csv -Path $CSVFile -NoTypeInformation
```

The code above is attributed to
https://xenit.se/blog/2022/07/07/retrieve-files-of-specific-filetype-from-sharepoint-site-using-powershell/

Tried changing the variable to

```
   $FileType = @("mp4","exe")   ( **my attempt** )
```

and changing like statement to contains

if ($Item["FileLeafRef"] -contains"*.$FileType") {

Comment: resolved using
Where {($_.FieldValues.FileLeafRef -like "*mp4*" -or $_.FieldValues.FileLeafRef -like '*.exe')

Comment: As aside, better not add items to an array using `+=` as it is extremely time and memory consuming. Simply capture the output of the loop using `$results = foreach ($DocLibrary in $DocLibraries) { ... }` and inside the loop just output the object. Also, a `[pscustomobject]` is ordered by default, so you can leave out `[ordered]`